# window.location.href not changing popup on enter button in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I have below frontend for the default popup of my chrome extension.

```
<form class="first-time-flow__form fullwidth">
    <h1 class="textaligncenter">Welcome</h1> 
    <div class="first-time-flow__textarea-wrapper">
        <label>Password (min 8 chars)</label>
        <input type="password" class="first-time-flow__input passwordinput" id="newpassword" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary loginpassword savePKbutton" id="btnlogin" disabled>Login</button>
</form>
```

I want that after the password is entered when the user will hit the enter key the submit button should be fired and the popup should be changed. I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#newpassword").keypress(function(event) {
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            $('#btnlogin').click();
         }
    });

   $('#btnlogin').on('click',function(){

        var password = $('#newpassword').val().trim();

        if(password.length >= 8){

        localStorage.password = password;

        chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
        popup:"login.html"
        });
        window.location.href = 'login.html';
        }
    });
});
```

This functionality works fine in the background without any error, the popup is also set to login.html but frontend is not getting changed. When I close and open chrome extension, the set popup *login.html* is shown. As the normal functionality works fine if user clicks submit button manually.

Comment: `keypress` event is only for letters and digits. You need `keydown` event. BTW start using devtools to set breakpoints and debug your code - the popup has its own devtools accessible by right-clicking inside the popup.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm. Now it works as expected. You can post this as answer if you wish.